# How to post constant and dynamic data in axios?

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

```
const insertProductInfoToDatabase = () => {
    products.map((product, index) => {
        axios
            .post(
                ProductPostAPI,
                {
                    orderNo: orderId,
                    customerId: "CD1",
                    itemId: product.prd_ID,
                    itemQnty: product.length,
                    itemRate: product.prd_Rate,
                    itemPrice: product.prd_Rate,
                },
                config
            )
            .then((response) => {
                return response;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
};
```

I have **two constant data and four dynamic data** and I want to post all these six data into my database through **Axios**. I'm a little bit confused about how to send data?

Comment: It's not the right way to do it. Please try to pass the products array in api and store it in the database using backend queries.

Comment: sending bulk data is better than sending multiple network call because when huge number of of network call goes to a server, server may  identify it as a bot and block your request well it only happens when huge number of requests come from same origin at the same time.
@sedhalsoni said it right.. convert your data into array and pass it to the server.

Comment: Actually, I've two APIs. One for sending total Cart Items and Total Price and if the data processed successfully then it generates an order-number. Then in other API, I'm sending individual order details (eg. Item price, Item ID) with the Order-Id. But the problem is when looping through those data it only sends the constant values and doesnt iterate.